# Set page title in static page view

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 1.3

I have a static page called `temp.ctp` located at `app/views/pages/temp.ctp`.

It is accessible from my site like: `localhost/pages/temp`

I am trying to set the page title from the view.

I have tried putting each of the following inside the temp.ctp file:

```
<?php $this->set("title_for_layout","Temp Temp Temp"); ?>
```

and

```
<? $this->pageTitle = 'Temp Temp Temp'; ?>
```

The entire file looks like this:

```
<?php $this->set("title_for_layout","Temp Temp Temp"); ?>


Hello World temp
```

And is using the default `layout` (for header and footer) that ships with cakephp 1.3.

Neither of which have worked. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Could you give us the content of temp.ctp. Or at least the <header>.

Comment: When you see the result in a browser, what HTML is being rendered?

Comment: @Marc after you asked me what html was rendered and I looked at the source I see the <title> tag is set to `CakePHP: the rapid development php framework:  Temp Temp Temp` so I am assuming the default layout for cake just appends the `title_for_layout` to the <title> tag instead of replacing it. I didn't realize this before because my title bar was not wide enough to view the whole thing. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to a thread on the CakePHP Google Group, it should be possible to use `$this->set("title_for_layout","Temp");` directly in your view - in CakePHP 1.3 that is, 1.2 uses `this->pageTitle = "Temp";`

According to a ticket, the pages controller still uses the $title instead of $title_for_layout though, so try that:

`$this->set("title","Temp");`

http://cakephp.lighthouseapp.com/projects/42648/tickets/511-pages-controller-needs-updating-for-title_for_layout

Comment: Damned reputation system, could only post a single link in the post above. Here's the link to the thread referred to: http://groups.google.com/group/cake-php/browse_thread/thread/30029a941f783161

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is, by default design, you should not be setting the page title from the view file. It's actually too late at that point. The Controller renders your final HTML in two parts: It puts the View inside of a Layout. The layout file is where the page title is set by default using `$title_for_layout`.

Take a look at cake/libs/view/layouts/default.ctp. In the `<head>` you'll see this, which explains what you've already described

```
<title>
    <?php __('CakePHP: the rapid development php framework:'); ?>
    <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
</title>
```

Because the Controller is where you are setting your viewVars, `$this->set("title_for_layout","Temp Temp Temp");`only works in the Controller. It does nothing in a view or layout file (as you document in your question).

You may have a good reason for skipping the layout and use a single static view .ctp file. To do this, set the **autoLayout** variable to false in your Controller. You can set this for the entire Controller just like you set the name, uses, etc variables: **`var $autoLayout = false;`**
or on a method by method basis with **`$this->autoLayout = false;`**.

Now Cake only renders your view .ctp file without the wrapper of a layout. All the viewVars are still available so you can use $title_for_layout if you want, otherwise hardcode a title. Either way you need to include your own `<head>`/`<title>` code at the top of the view .ctp file because it's not include with the layout anymore.